# Dynamic navbar in asp core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I am a noob at mvc and i have glanced at or read about 50 questions and articles about this but I'm not sure how to do this.

I used the MVC Core template app from VS2017 and that includes the navbar. I added login, cookies, some actions and controllers and it's working fine. Now whatI'm stuck at is how to display user icon instead of login button on the navbar.
I guess I would read cookie with user id and if it exists would render the user icon and if not the login button (which is third party single sign on process).

BUT, the navbar is in the _layout and I don't know how to pass data there. So I read at a few places I should inherit base view and at some other places that I should create partial view. Being a noob I got lost.

So, now i added to my Layout page this

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml");
```

this contins the navbar copied from the _Layout.
How do I link the data I want to this view?
I'd like to use razor `@ViewBag.FirstMenuItem` or something like that like in my other views.

Is this the right approach? I imagine this would be the most common thing ever but I get confused with articles that are written for older MVC versions and the pieces of code that are not clear to me where exactly should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Use ViewComponents which are new and are similar to old partial views.